# Serial communication with scilab in Linux

Tags: linux, serial-port, communication, scilab

Can you please provide some examples of serial communication with scilab in Linux. When I gave the command:

```
h=openserial(1,"9600,n,8,1");
```

I am getting the following error:

```
-->h=openserial(1,"9600,n,8,1");
!--error 999 
TCL_EvalStr,  at line 1
bad option "-mode": should be one of -blocking, -buffering, -buffersize, -encoding, -eofchar, or -translation
while executing
"fconfigure file114 -mode 9600,n,8,1"
at line      27 of function openserial called by :  
h=openserial(1,"9600,n,8,1");
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/webhp?q=%22bad+option+%22-mode%22:+should+be+one+of+-blocking%2C+-buffering%2C+-buffersize%2C+-encoding%2C+-eofchar%2C+or+-translation%22&oq=%22bad+option+%22-mode%22:+should+be+one+of+-blocking%2C+-buffering%2C+-buffersize%2C+-encoding%2C+-eofchar%2C+or+-translation%22&gs_l=serp.3...4434.5090.1.5315.2.2.0.0.0.0.0.0..0.0.les%3B..0.2...1c.1.ixOUV6Dx7Qg&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=b87aba38e7093c75&bpcl=39468505&ion=1&biw=1438&bih=843

Answer (score 0):

A simple serial communication with for example an Arduino device needs only the baudrate specified as the second argument in openserial. Seems like your other variables in the string argument (n?) are messing up.

Scilab 5.4 example, with Serial Toolbox, for com port 3 and baudrate 9600. 5s delay before trying to read serial.

```
h = openserial(3,"9600");
xpause(5000000);
data = readserial(h);
closeserial(h);
```

Together with some serial spamming code on your arduino device you should receive a string of data at each run in Scilab.

Example code for serial on Arduino device:

```
int cc=0;

void setup(){
   Serial.begin(9600); 
}

void loop(){
  Serial.println(cc);
  if (cc<10){
  cc++;
  }
  else{
  cc=0;
  }
  delay(100);
}
```